# Shuffle a tuple in python

Tags: python

I define a tuple called `states` in my test environment. I then wish to step through this tuple in a random manner as I test my system:

```
st = time.time()
for s in sorted(states,key=lambda k: random.random()):
    my_system.set_state(s)
    test.confirm_state(s)
```

Each state should only be visited once. Is this the most pythonic way of shuffling my tuple?

Comment: You are using exactly what I advocated before. Since `random.shuffle()` would require you to create a list copy of the tuple first, I'd say your approach is fine. Closing as a dupe, as your basic question is essentially primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 4):

Python comes with batteries included. Use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) on a sequence.

You must be aware that `random.shuffle` operates in place on a mutable sequence, which is why it does not return the list itself.

```
l = list(states)
random.shuffle(l) # random.shuffle is returning None
for x in l:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Now you have 3 lines instead of 1. Why is this more pythonic than what the OP has? :-P

Comment: You have a point, as always :) Is shortness more pythonic than using what the library provides?

Comment: Pythonicness is in the eye of the beholder. `sorted()` is also something the library provides, giving it `random.random()` as a key is just as pythonic, and it works just as well.

Comment: `len(set(tuple(sorted(range(3), key=lambda x: random.randrange(2))) for i in range(10000))) == 5` but there are 6 permutations of `[0, 1, 2]`. Using `key=<something random>` can't generate all permutations with equal probability unless `<something random>` doesn't generate duplicates. In particular, the algorithm of `sorted` (timsort) is stable and thus can't generate `(2, 1, 0)` using `randrange(2)` as key (proof left for the reader). That's a strawman random-key, granted, but I hope it gets the point across: watch out for duplicate random keys!